# How to get image from camera

Tags: android

I have tried many codes from stackoverflow and internet.But I am able to find how to pick image from camera.I have used the following code,but data.getData() always returns null.Dont know how to solve.Pleas help this.

```
 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
           if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA1);
                }
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
                {  
                    if (requestCode == 30 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK&&data!null)
                    {  

                        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

                    }  
                }
```

Comment: You are not calling `data.getData()`. And `data.getData()` is supposed to be `null` for the response to `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. You should be getting a `Bitmap` in your `photo` variable, in the code in your question. This is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics).

Comment: I have updated the code.This is the code i am using.But the image is not getting placed in the imageview.data.getData() always returns null and it wont go inside if condition.Any brief solution please?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

Comment: Remove `if(data.getData()!null){` and the corresponding `}`.

Comment: thanks.I will update you whether it works or not.

Comment: Still not working.I have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code @Thrishool,

```
private static final int CAMERA = 1;

//choosing the image from camera
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);



//now get the data from the onActivity result

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
        byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
        String temp = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.e("savedImage",temp);

        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Try this and let me know @Thrishool

Comment: Bro.Actually,when i picking image from gallery,i got the uri from data.getData() and uploaded to firebase.Now if i am getting image from camera,how to upload into firebase.Can you help me

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebase image upload. But I hope this helps you @ThrishoolMSM. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/image-upload-to-firebase-in-android-application--cms-29934