# How to get image from camera in android

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

This is the code i am using.

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new 
Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA1); 
 }

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
    if (requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA1){
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
 }     
}
}
```

I am getting the following exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result 
    ResultInfo{who=null, request=5, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: url
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4360)
```

Comment: go for this link helps you alot, https://android.jlelse.eu/androids-new-image-capture-from-a-camera-using-file-provider-dd178519a954

Comment: Yeah.Found the answer

Comment: where did you go wrong here in the code @ThrishoolMSM ?

Comment: is my answer describe what was missing ?

Comment: The problem is in the OnActivityResult. Look at the exception message it says Failure delivering result. It says that there is something problem in getting the image data. @ismailalaoui

Comment: yes the image url , if the app doesn't have permission to write and read from data storage , it will trigger this error

Comment: @BrahmaDatta i got  answer.https://stackoverflow.com/a/56421777/9202667

Comment: you are not allowed to re-ask same question regardless of how important is it to you. If you have an update to previous question - edit it, not ask new one

Answer (score 0):

```
//This Function Called on Onclick
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;

            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {

                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        mActivity.getPackageName() + ".provider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);

            }
        }
    }

     @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO:
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                        Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: currentPHotoPath >> " + currentPhotoPath);
                        Glide.with(mContext).load(currentPhotoPath).into(imgCamera);

                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This isn't working.I have tried this already

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have both **Camera Permission** and **READ/WRITE** External Storage Permissions.

Comment: yes.i provided both